# SVG: Event Propagation

Tags: javascript, events, svg

I have an SVG with 2 Rects inside. They are overlaying.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <rect id="rect1" fill="blue" x="40" y="40" height="20" width="20"/>
  <rect id="rect2" fill="red" x="40" y="40" height="20" width="20"/>
</svg>
```

When you use this code, you will see a red rectangle, because rect2 is above rect1. Both rectangles have the same onClick-listener. But only the listener of rect2 is beeing triggered even if Propagation is not stopped. If I set **pointer-events: none** for rect2, the listener of rect 1 is triggered.
But my problem is that I want to decide in the callback of rect2-listener whether the event should be propagated to rect1 or not.

Can I set the pointer-events dynamically inside my callback? Is there a method which allows me to repeat the event after I set **pointer-events: none** or a method that propagates the event to the underlying rect?

Hope you get my question right, if not I ask you to comment so that we can clearify misunderstandings.

Comment: you can't repeat the event but you can presumably call the handler function directly.

Comment: can you make a fiddle to see your code on action?